# Record is read-only in trigger

Tags: trigger

> CaseDemoRecordType: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.CaseDemoRecordType: line 17, column 1

```java
trigger CaseDemoRecordType on Case (After insert , After update)
{
    if((trigger.isAfter) && (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate))
    {
        List<RecordType> recordTyp = [Select id, Name, Sobjecttype from RecordType];
        List<Case> LstCs = [select id, CaseNumber, RecordTypeId from case];
    
        for(Case cs : Trigger.new)
        {
            for(RecordType RecTyp : recordTyp)
            {
            
                if(cs.RecordTypeID == RecTyp.id)
                {
                    if(RecTyp.Name == 'School zone')
                    {
                        cs.Description = 'This is SCHOOL ZONE';
                        system.debug('This is SCHOOL zONE^^^^^'+RecTyp.Name);
                    }
                    else
                        cs.Description = 'This is COLLEGE ZONE';
                    system.debug('This is COLLEGE zONE......'+RecTyp.Name);
            
                    system.debug('The REcord Type Ids..............'+cs.RecordTypeId);

                }
            }
            update cs;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I've downvoted this because you haven't shown any attempt at research. [Searching for similar questions should have turned up a fair number of results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=execution+of+AfterInsert+caused+by%3A+System.FinalException%3A+Record+is+read-only), as would [using a search engine with the literal text of your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=CaseDemoRecordType%3A+execution+of+AfterInsert+caused+by%3A+System.FinalException%3A+Record+is+read-only+Trigger.CaseDemoRecordType%3A+line+17%2C+column+1)

Answer (score 5):

In an "after" trigger context, the records in trigger context variables (trigger.new, trigger.newMap) are read-only.

If you want to update the same records being triggered, then you should be using the *"before"* trigger context instead. That would allow you to remove the dml update in your loop (dml and queries should *never appear in loops*<sup>1</sup>).

This is not the only issue with your trigger code. Other issues include:

- Your logic should not be in the trigger itself. You should be using a trigger framework. At the very least, get this logic into a separate apex class and call the method from your trigger. This greatly improves testability.
- Queries without filters are generally a bad idea
- You don't need the query on `Case`
- Loop over the trigger records first (to gather record type ids), *then* query the recordtypes ...and store the results in a map so you can get rid of that nested loop (i.e. you can just have the loop over `Case` and get at the record type information via `myRecTypeMap.get(myCase.RecordTypeId)`)
- Or, even better, just use the SObject describe information to get the recordTypeInfo (e.g. `Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosById()`)
- Not using braces for the if/else blocks (just the `else` in your case) is inconsistent. It makes it so that only the following statement is included. This is a source of bugs (which, due to its subtlety, makes this issue hard(er) to find). Just use braces for every if/else if/else.

<sup>1: Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and can clearly explain why it must be in a loop. This does not describe your situation.</sup>